# Outlook instance null after use of MailItem.Display() and MailItem.Close() are run

Tags: c#, outlook, automation, office-interop

**Short Version:**
I need to display the currently selected mailItem on the screen. Then later I need to close the window. The issue is that closing the mailItem window ends the Outlook application instance.

**Detail:**
I have a function that calls MailItem.Display(false) to display the currently selected mail item on the screen. Then a separate tool does some "on the glass" automation (moves the mouse about clicking things). Then when its done I have a function that closes the window. The issue is that the when I close the mail item inspector window my outlook instance closes all together. My class where the outlook instance was constructed remains as it should, but now future functions calls all fail since the Outlook application object I globally defined in my class is now null.

;

;

Here is the first function to display the mailItem:

```
    public string DisplayMail(string ID){                      
        try{
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)(oNamespace.GetItemFromID(ID,activeFolder.StoreID));

            mailItem.Display(false);
            mailItem.GetInspector.Activate(); //just to bring the window to the front if it isn't

            return("Success");

        } catch (Exception e){
            return(ErrPrefix + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is the code that closes the mailItem:

```
    public string CloseMail(string ID){
        try{
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)(oNamespace.GetItemFromID(ID,activeFolder.StoreID));
            mailItem.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);

            return("Success");

        } catch (Exception e){
            return(ErrPrefix + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is some related global code:

```
oApp = new Outlook.Application();
oNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
```

I am using .Net Core 2.0, the on the glass work requires it. I am rebuilding an older tool that did the same work but was very slow and hard to error check. I am trying to keep as much off the screen as possible to speed things up, so I don't display the main outlook window or mail items unless I absolutely need to. They runs invisible in the background. Unfortunately I must display the mailItem in this case so the other tool can do the on the glass work. From what I can tell if outlook detects the last outlook window closing event the application instance dies. Which is weird because if a window is never displayed and I do work in the background the instance will continue until I release/kill it or the class containing the instance is deconstructed.

**Thanks for any help.**

Comment: Where is oApp defined? Since I just seem to see the instantiation.

Comment: The oApp is defined when my class is constructed. The way the calling tool works is it creates the my class at the time the tool kicks off and my class instance remains through to when the tool closes. At this time, my class is deconstructed. Outlook is the only thing that dies prematurely.